# How to save results from an API call that uses a pandas column for the requests before the whole thing times out when using apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I have a pandas dataframe with strings that I'm using to query an API and return the results.

I'm trying to call the API using a function and `.apply` and then save the results from the api call into a csv file. The problem is that I'm trying to do 10000+ requests and my kernel/notebook crashes. Basically I'm trying to do a big operation and I'm guessing I'm running out of memory. So I'm trying to think of a way I can do these api calls and save the results and not have it all crash. My version with `.apply` works with a small amount of data but not once it gets larger.

So my notebook code currently looks something like this.

```
df = pd.read_csv('bigstringlist.csv')
df = df.loc[0:3000]
```

My function looks something like this.

```
def api_fetch_func(address):
   
    sleep(.2)
    API_PRIVATE = 'awewaefawefawef'
    encoded = urllib.parse.quote(address)
    query ='https://apitocall' + str(encoded) + \
           '.json?limit=1&key=' \
           + API_PRIVATE

    response = requests.get(query)
    while True:
        try:
            jsonResponse = response.json()
            break
        except:
            response = requests.get(query)
    
    try:
        return jsonResponse['results']
    except:
        return
    else:
        return
```

Then I'm calling the function like so

```
df['response_col'] = df['string_col'].apply(api_fetch_func)
```

Something tells me that `.apply` isn't the right thing to do here. Would be better if I just push the api responses into an array or another dataframe?

Should I just use `.iterrows` to loop over the list of strings and call the function? Something tells me `.apply` tries to jam too much into memory and that's why this doesn't work.

So I was going to try

```
results = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # call API
    # push results to array
```

Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why do you call the API in a while True loop ?

Comment: It worked fine for me. Open to other ways of doing it.

Comment: But why did you code that ?

Comment: What's a better way to do it? Not very experienced with python

Comment: Call once, no need pf while loop

Answer (score 0):

If it's a memory issue, what I'd do is write the API calling function as a generator with the `yield` statement. Then, you can loop through the `api_fetch_function` generator and save smaller data frames for the csv files rather than holding everything in memory in one go.

```py
for idx, response in api_fetch_generator():
    if idx % 500 == 0:
        df = create_df() # create a fresh df as you did above with 'string_col'.
    df['response_col'] = df['string_col'].apply(response)
    
    if (idx % 500 == 0) and idx != 0:
        # Save the df using idx to control the file name
        df.to_csv(f"response_batch_{idx / 500}.csv")
# Combine the csv's after everything is saved.
```